# Nodejs - catch upload to ftp error(ftp module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, node-modules

How can I catch an upload error in node js via ftp? For example when my computer loses the connection. I am using ftp module and nothing of this(error, close or end) throws any errors. Or may be there are any other solutions, i mean another npm module?

```
var Client = require('ftp');
var c = new Client();

c.on('ready', callback);
c.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
c.on('close', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
c.on('end', function(){
    console.log("END");
});

c.connect({
    host: host,
    port: port,
    user: username,
    password: password
});
...
c.put(uploadfile, uploadpath, onupload);
```

Comment: The `put()` method also has a callback function with an error parameter.

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt work too.

Comment: That repo hasn't been updated in 2.5 years. Maybe just broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is not the best idea to edit the library, but i solved my problem by adding this code

```
    if(err.indexOf("ECONNRESET") > -1){
        this._reset();
    }
```

after

```
sock.once('error', function(err) {
    self.emit('error', err);
```

on *965* line in *connection.js* of ftp library.